# Set limit on sum of elements in Java Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an array where the number of elements is randomized from 3 to 20 where the sum of all the elements is 45. My problem is that I cannot set a limit so the sum does not exceed the value of 45.

Assuming there are 4 elements:

My current output:
15 21 19 26

What I need:
7 11 23 4

```
public static void startGame(int[] cards) {
    cards = new int[45];
    Random rand = new Random();
    int sum = 45;
    int numStacks = 1;
    numStacks = rand.nextInt(18) + 3;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numStacks; i++) {
        cards[i] = (rand.nextInt(45) + 1) - numStacks;
        sum += cards[i];
        System.out.println(cards[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, if you want the sum of the elements to be less then 45, why did you set `sum` to 45?

Comment: Should the length of the array variable `cards` be `numStacks`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I need it to be equal to 45 exactly. Sorry if I misworded the question.

Comment: @sushant yes it needs to be.

Comment: Don't clarify in comments; edit your question.

Comment: @David___S__ What is the significance of 18 here?

Comment: @sushant i want the number of stacks to be from 3 to 18 that does not really matter

Answer (score 1):

You can give this implementation a shot:

```
  public static void startGame() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int sum = 45;
    int numStacks = 1;
    numStacks = rand.nextInt(18) + 3;
    int[] cards = new int[numStacks];
    int upperBound = 20;
    int lowerBound = 3;
    if(lowerBound*numStacks > sum || upperBound*numStacks < sum) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot make the stack - improper distribution for numStacks :%d upperBound: %d lowerBound: %d", numStacks, upperBound, lowerBound));
    }
    Arrays.fill(cards, lowerBound);
    for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++)
    {
        boolean keepCalculating = true;
        while(keepCalculating) {
            int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(numStacks);
            int nextValue = cards[randomIndex] + 1;
            if(nextValue <= upperBound) {
                cards[randomIndex] = nextValue;
                keepCalculating = false;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("numStacks: %d%n", numStacks);
    System.out.printf("cards: %s%n", Arrays.toString(cards));
    System.out.printf("sum: %d%n", Arrays.stream(cards).sum());
}
```

`cards` has the result.
Sample run:

```
numStacks: 7
cards: [7, 7, 5, 8, 5, 2, 11]
sum: 45
```

In case, it cannot make the stack, here is the exception that it throws.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot make the stack - improper distribution for numStacks :20 upperBound: 20 lowerBound: 3
```

If you want the program to "always" calculate a stack, then you can try this code:

```
  public static void startGame() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int sum = 45;
    int numStacks = 1;
    int maxNumberOfCards = 18;
    int minNumberOfCards = 3;
    int upperBound = 20;
    int lowerBound = 3;
    boolean calculateValidNumberOfStacks = true;
    while(calculateValidNumberOfStacks) {
        int checkVal = rand.nextInt(maxNumberOfCards) + minNumberOfCards;
        if(lowerBound*checkVal < sum && upperBound*checkVal > sum) {
            numStacks = checkVal;
            calculateValidNumberOfStacks = false;
        }
    }
    int[] cards = new int[numStacks];
    Arrays.fill(cards, lowerBound);
    for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
        boolean keepCalculating = true;
        while(keepCalculating) {
            int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(numStacks);
            int nextValue = cards[randomIndex] + 1;
            if(nextValue <= upperBound) {
                cards[randomIndex] = nextValue;
                keepCalculating = false;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("numStacks: %d%n", numStacks);
    System.out.printf("cards: %s%n", Arrays.toString(cards));
    System.out.printf("sum: %d%n", Arrays.stream(cards).sum());
}
```

Comment: That's not how you get a random int from an instance of `rnd.` `rnd.nextInt()` is how. Your solution is not properly distributed (Pigeon hole principle). It'll get stuck and loop forever if you get bad input (that's a pretty nasty failure mode. An exception would have been a lot nicer).

Comment: @rzwitserloot Noted. Could you please explain how the solution is not properly distributed. If there is a solution, then the loop will find it. Please correct my understanding

Comment: @rzwitserloot Fair point, My bad! I have modified the code to use `int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(numStacks)`

Comment: @rzwitserloot I see your point about improper distribution. I have added an exception.

Comment: There aren't an infinite amount of numbers that `.nextDouble()` could possibly make. It's a computer; there is a finite number. Let's say it's 25 numbers. If you then do some mapping that maps those 25 numbers onto, say, 1-4, then.. it doesn't fit. 25/4 isn't 'whole'. One of these numbers is going to come up more often. The actual numbers are considerably larger, but the principle stands. `.nextInt(x)` fixes this.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Noted! Thanks for the explanation.